# Entity Framework Check if multiple records exist before insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to figure out the best way to insert multiple records (over 200) if they do not exist, without making a trip for each record to check if it exists, which I do like this:

```
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    if (!context.Nodes.Any(x => x.Name == node.Name))
    {
        context.Nodes.Add(new NWatchNode(node));
    }

    try
    {
        if (context.Nodes.Local.Any())
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that `node.Name` is unique in the table in the database, you could do something like this narrow your list of nodes to ones that don't exist:

```
var missingRecords = nodes.Where(x => !context.Nodes.Any(z => z.Name == x.Name)).ToList();
```

Then insert the missing records with something like:

```
context.Nodes.AddRange(missingRecords);
```

Comment: Does that still do an individual SQL statement for each node, or does it send it all in one request?

Comment: I am not sure how Entity Framework handles AddRange behind the scenes.  I believe it should do it all as one large transaction and save the transaction when you call `context.SaveChanges();`  You could probably run a SQL profiler and see how it is handled on the SQL server.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for obtaining the missing records.  Will it send one statement for each record it is checking?

Comment: I believe Entity Framework does work recursively in checking the records, yes.  If you want it all server side then look at stored procedures.

Comment: The query will be one SQL statement; the insert will be one separate insert statement for each record (inside a transaction)